# Convert to mysql TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

How can i convert this values to insert into mysql TIMESTAMP.

```
$time=12 am;

$time=date("H:i:s", strtotime($mtime));
```

the above thing doesn't work

is there any better solution to do this.

Comment: You mean a literal mySQL time stamp, or a `DATETIME` value?

Comment: i mean a literal mySQL time stamp

Comment: You have a few typos above - I assume you mean `$mtime = "12 am";`. Note use of `$mtime` as you use later in `strtotime()`

Comment: Do you mean 12am *today?* A timestamp always consists of a date and a time

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're seeing '00:00:00' and assuming that's wrong...it's not. '00:00:00' is how midnight is represented. If you want to get *today* at midnight this will do it:

```
$now = time();
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $now), date('d', $now), date('Y', $now));
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

This will return a string like this: `2011-10-04 00:00:00` which I think is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $time = "12am";
 $time=date("H:i:s", strtotime($time));
```

That should work

Comment: but the value showing me 00:00:00 . Is there any possible reason for this.

Comment: that's because 12am is 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
$time=12 am;
$time=date("H:i:s", strtotime($mtime));
```

`$time = 12 am`, but you're trying `strtotime($mtime)`. maybe your problem in wrong variable?